# First use BEM. What I doing wrong?

Tags: css, bem

I try to use BEM in first time and I think that I don't quite understand it. **Is it necessarily to assign classes to all elements, include** `li` and `a`? I would be very grateful to receive your advice on this peace of code:

```
  <header>
<div class="container container-1170">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default header-menu">

        <div class="navbar-header header-menu__toggle">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img src="./img/sprite.png" class="header-menu__logo ico_header-logo" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right header-menu__list">
            <li class="header-menu__list__item item"><a href="#" class="item__href item__href--active"></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown header-menu__list__item item">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle item__href item__href--dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-list">
                <li class="drop-list__item"><a href="#"></a>
                  <ul class="in-drop-item">
                    <li class="in-drop-item__item"><a href="#" class="in-drop-item__item__href"></a></li>
                    <li class="in-drop-item__item"><a href="#" class="in-drop-item__item__href"></a></li>
                    <li class="in-drop-item__item"><a href="#" class="in-drop-item__item__href"></a></li>
                    <li class="in-drop-item__item"><a href="#" class="in-drop-item__item__href"></a></li>
                    <li class="in-drop-item__item"><a href="#" class="in-drop-item__item__href"></a></li>
                    <li class="in-drop-item__item"><a href="#" class="in-drop-item__item__href"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="drop-list__item"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="drop-list__item"><a href="#"></a></li>  
                <li class="drop-list__item"><a href="#"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="header-menu__list__item item"><a href="#" class="item__href"></a></li>
            <li class="header-menu__list__item item"><a href="#" class="item__href"></a></li>
            <li class="header-menu__list__item item"><a href="#" class="item__href"></a></li>
            <li class="header-menu__list__item item"><a href="#" class="item__href"></a></li>
            <li class="header-menu__list__item item"><a href="#" class="item__href"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key concept of bem is reusability of your code. If you can reuse it, you should give it a class. It helps to avoid nested selectors and make things more modular. I strongly recommend not to do so, if this is not necessary, but if you feel that this elements never will be apart of this structure, you can make some cascade style rules for them, but be careful, this feeling is usually tricky.

Also, I've found some other mistake - you should avoid "elements of elements". Here is the explanation:
https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-does-bem-not-recommend-using-elements-within-elements-block__elem1__elem2